# What effects do weather changes have on your character?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know Skyrim features weather like snow / hail / rain.  What effects (if any) do the different weather types have on your character (especially combat)?

Comment: Some of the dragon shouts even change the weather!~

Comment: I've read in a few places that it can decrease your visibility, decrease your move speed and even flood lower altitude places, but I haven't seen any of this yet so I can't prove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Walking around Winterhold, snow and windstorms do decrease the distance in which you can see.

I haven't noticed any heavy impact on move speed, it did feel a bit slower but that might also have been the effect of the current fatigue state and weight of the character and its items.

I haven't seen lower places flooded by rain, but that doesn't impose effects on the character anyway.

---

None of these effects have an effect on battle, expect for accidentally running into opponents when traveling with a faster horse and not paying attention to your surroundings. Some of the wild monsters I saw around Winterhold were made stronger themselves; so they didn't add weather effects to your character to make it even harder to fight these monsters, I think they only added it to the area to make it more creepy and to denote that you could encounter stronger monsters...

Comment: Sadly, this seems to be true.  I was hoping for random snowstorms that made e.g. monsters or ice spells more powerful, but the weather system seems to be localized and largely cosmetic :(

Answer (score 3):

Playing a Khajiit character, I've noticed that I would get a layer of snow on top of my tail when it was snowing.  That's the only effect of weather on my character that I've seen so far.